# Scala akka how create entry point for event source?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, event-sourcing, typed

I've been struggling to learn akka actors and **I REALLY need your help** guys!

So my goal is basically to write a simple auction agent. And AKKA actually has an example on how to do it https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/replicated-eventsourcing-auction.html! The problem is, I have no idea how to run it. Now I've spent like 3 days on trying to get it to work before asking for your help but I've completely lost it..:/

So, I started to learn about typed actors first and how they work. I've managed to actually print something on the screen by creating a simple actor system like this that I've found on the internet where I have a simple order actor (typed) and on its apply method I can print the incoming order:

```
//Entry point inside main(args <...>)
val orderProcessor: ActorSystem[OrderProcessor.Order] = ActorSystem(OrderProcessor(), "main")
//create a new order
orderProcessor ! Order(0, "Bananas")
//<..printing something inside the actor when receiving this message>
```

Now the auction example uses **EventSourcedBehavior** so I came to the conclusion that next step is to learn about event sourcing in Akka (hopefully this isn't confusing so far or hopefully I'm on the right path) So I went to the official documentation of Akka's event sourcing https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence.html#module-info and I took their example:

```
object MyPersistentBehavior {
  sealed trait Command
  final case class Add(data: String) extends Command
  case object Clear extends Command

  sealed trait Event
  final case class Added(data: String) extends Event
  case object Cleared extends Event

  final case class State(history: List[String] = Nil)

  val eventHandler: (State, Event) => State = { (state, event) =>
    event match {
      case Added(data) => state.copy((data :: state.history).take(5))
      case Cleared     => State(Nil)
    }
  }

  val commandHandler: (State, Command) => Effect[Event, State] = { (state, command) =>
    command match {
      case Add(data) => Effect.persist(Added(data))
      case Clear     => Effect.persist(Cleared)
    }
  }

  def apply(id: String): Behavior[Command] =
    EventSourcedBehavior[Command, Event, State](
      persistenceId = PersistenceId.ofUniqueId(id),
      emptyState = State(Nil),
      commandHandler = commandHandler,
      eventHandler = eventHandler)
}
```

Now that is great! Very simple and concise.

The problem is, I don't understand where the entry point is?
Like for **orderProcessor** (first example that I've shown) it is obviously just to create a new ActorSystem and thats it, but I can't find any information on this example. I've tried soooo many different projects from github and none of them very simple enough for me to understand. To be fair most of them had tests, but tests didn't really help me much.

Please, any help, **any tips would be SOOO much appreciated**, I'm really struggling guys!

***Love Yall !<3***

Comment: I suggest starting with the tutorial, which explains how to create the actor system [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/tutorial_2.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to obtain `ActorRef[MessangeType]` to be able to send `MessageType` to it.

Existing actor has `context` (passed as an argument with `Behavior` definition) where you can create a child like:

```
val actorRef = context.spawn(behavior)
```

but you can also create it top-level from `ActorSystem` (then the system is the parent directly)

```
val actorRef = system.systemActorOf(behavior)
```

So in your case it could be something like:

```
val actorRef = system.systemActorOf(MyPersistentBehavior("test"))
actorRef ! MyPersistentBehavior.Add("test")
```

alternatively you can `context.spawn` it inside `Behavior[OrderProcessor.Order]` defined for your `ActorSystem`, then you'll talk to `actorRef` through `system` which would send commands to persistent actor.

Comment: Isn't system.systemActorOf from classic akka? I want it to be typed. I've tried it like this:


`val actorRef: ActorSystem[MyPersistentBehavior.Command] = ActorSystem(MyPersistentBehavior("test"), "main")
    actorRef ! MyPersistentBehavior.Add("test")`

But when I put a breakpoint on commandHandler code doesnt reach the Add match arm.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's typed, see: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/7abc41cf4e7e8827393b181cd06c5f8ea684e696/akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/ActorSystem.scala#L165

Comment: I don't know your whole example but an educated guess it: your whole program is two line long, it terminates `main` and `system` is shutdown before any executor has a chance of running the code (`Future`s are async). But without the code nobody can tell, and this is a separate question not fitting for solving in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your paint, unfortunately Akka Documentation give only Snippets as samples in documentation and they are most of the time not complete and hard to understand.

You can find in their Github complete [examples](https://github.com/akka/akka-samples) I guess you can understands things better this way.

If you want to see a full fledged Proof of Concept application with Akka, I have a blog about it which you can find [here](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/).